# How to generate reports excluding weekends in Servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I have a task created in Snow (lets say on 1st of the month) and closed the task (on 7th of the month), I need to create a report on the tasks with the SLA of 5 working days.

[Task Report Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbFv1.png)
This image however tasks 5 days as SLA which also includes weekends, I need a solution to exclude the weekends and to calculate the SLA on weekdays only.

I found no options on excluding the weekends in the conditions of the report in Service Now